# How do you create a multi-line text inside a ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Since `List` doesn't look like its configurable to remove the row dividers at the moment, I'm using a `ScrollView` with a `VStack` inside it to create a vertical layout of text elements. Example below:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        // ...
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mattis ullamcorper tortor, nec finibus sapien imperdiet non. Duis tristique eros eget ex consectetur laoreet.")
            .lineLimit(0)
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
}
```

The resulting `Text` rendered is truncated single-line. Outside of a `ScrollView` it renders as multi-line. How would I achieve this inside a `ScrollView` other than explicitly setting a height for the `Text` frame ?

Comment: What happens if you give the `Text` a frame with a width?

Comment: The `Text` shrinks to the specified width as expected. But still single-line @Fogmeister

Comment: you can calculate height for text according width. And set it to TEXT frame.  it will work fine

Comment: This is a bug. There is a workaround for it... https://icalvin.dev/post/403

Answer (score 117, accepted):

In Xcode 11 GM:

For any `Text` view in a stack nested in a scrollview, use the `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` workaround:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Text(someString)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

This also works if there are multiple multiline texts:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Text(someString)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        Text(anotherLongString)
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }
}
```

If the contents of your stack are dynamic, the same solution works:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        // Place a single empty / "" at the top of your stack.
        // It will consume no vertical space.
        Text("")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

        ForEach(someArray) { someString in
            Text(someString)
              .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error doesn't throw in Preview right? Because in preview it did show the same truncation behaviour as before.. but without the `Spacer()`it worked just fine..

Comment: Awesome! I was using geometry reader.. but too much for too less

Comment: As of beta 5, `.infinity` crashes for me, but `.frame(idealHeight: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)` works.

Comment: I have many dynamically generated views inside of a scrollview, some of them containing Text several layers down their respective view tree. Unfortunately, none of these solutions work -- I still see a bunch of Text fields compressed into a single line. Has anyone experienced a similar issue? I'm on the GM release of Xcode

Comment: Why does this work? it would almost make more sense to have the true and false the other way round, as the vertical height should be flexible and not fixed.

Answer (score 7):

You can force views to fill their ideal size, for example in a vertical ScrollView:

```
ScrollView {
    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mattis ullamcorper tortor, nec finibus sapien imperdiet non. Duis tristique eros eget ex consectetur laoreet.")
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
```

Feels a little better to me than modifying the frame.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like there is bug in SwiftUI. For now you have to specify height for your VStack container

```
ScrollView {
      VStack {
           // ...
               Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mattis ullamcorper tortor, nec finibus sapien imperdiet non. Duis tristique eros eget ex consectetur laoreet.")
                    .lineLimit(nil)
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 500)
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me with **Beta 3** - no spacer, no width constraint, flexible height constraint:

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Text(longText)
            .lineLimit(nil)
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .frame(idealHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to just make sure to set the alignment for your stack:

`VStack(alignment: .leading)`

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        // ...
        Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer mattis ullamcorper tortor, nec finibus sapien imperdiet non. Duis tristique eros eget ex consectetur laoreet.")
            .lineLimit(0)
    }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
}
```

This way you don't need the `fixedSize` as the layout is properly defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
ScrollView {
    Text(LocalizedStringKey("Lorem Ipsum"))
        .font(.footnote)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding()
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.