# SwiftUI multiline text always truncating at 1 line

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create a list of options for a user to choose from. The debug preview shows the general look and feel. My problem is that passing `nil` to `.lineLimit` in `MultipleChoiceOption` doesn't allow the text to grow beyond 1 line. How can I correct this?

```
struct Card<Content: View> : View {
    private let content: () -> Content
    init(content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }

    private let shadowColor = Color(red: 69 / 255, green: 81 / 255, blue: 84 / 255, opacity: 0.1)

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            self.content()
                .padding()
                .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 22, style: .continuous)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .shadow(color: shadowColor, radius: 10, x: 0, y: 5)
            )
            }
            .aspectRatio(0.544, contentMode: .fit)
            .padding()
    }
}

struct MultipleChoiceOption : View {
    var option: String
    @State var isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? .gray : .white)
                .cornerRadius(6)
                .border(Color.gray, width: 1, cornerRadius: 6)
            Text(self.option)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(self.isSelected ? .white : .black)
                .padding()
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .lineLimit(nil)
        }
    }
}

struct MultipleChoice : View {
    @State var selectedIndex = 1

    var options: [String] = [
        "Hello World",
        "How are you?",
        "This is a longer test This is a longer test This is a longer test This is a longer test This is a longer test This is a longer test"
    ]

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(self.options.indices) { i in
                        MultipleChoiceOption(option: self.options[i],
                                             isSelected: i == self.selectedIndex)
                            .tapAction { self.selectedIndex = i }


                    }
                }
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width)
            }
        }
            .padding()
    }
}

struct MultipleChoiceCard : View {
    var question: String = "Is this a question?"

    var body: some View {
        Card {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text(self.question)
                MultipleChoice()
            }
        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ContentView_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
//        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                MultipleChoiceCard()
                Button(action: {

                }) {
                    Text("Next")
                        .padding()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(Color.orange)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
                .padding()
//                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello"))
//        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Please see this answer for Xcode 11 GM:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604599/30602

Summary: add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` — this worked for me in my use case.

Answer (score 39):

The modifier `fixedSize()` prevents the truncation of multiline text.

**Inside HStack**

```
Text("text").fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
```

**Inside VStack**

```
Text("text").fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Comment: It's the opposite.

Comment: I fixed the opposite logic. Should be good now.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a bug in SwiftUI causing the nil lineLimit to not work.

If you MUST fix this now, you can wrap a UITextField:
https://icalvin.dev/post/403

Comment: It is not always a bug. Reordering and reorganizing the view's layout can fix the issue, but of course that is usually not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Text` had a padding to top and it was looking fine when keyboard is not presented but when keyboard gets presented multiline text turns into single line and only part of the content was visible.

Wrapping the view with `ScrollView` fixed the issue, since when keyboard appears on the screen, View height decreases so Text component can't find enough space to display it's content, `ScrollView` enables `Text` to display whole content in multiple lines

Answer (score -6):

I had the same problem and used this workaround:

Add the modifier:
`.frame(idealHeight: .infinity)`

Comment: Afraid this solution crashes for me.