# Text.lineLimit() behavior is inconsistent in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have some description text in a VStack, and I'd like to limit it to 3 lines. My understanding is that I modify `Text()` with a `.lineLimit(3)` modifier. However, when I do this, some of the descriptions get capped at *3* lines, while others get capped at *1*. There doesn't seem to be any consistency as to where this happens.

I thought this could be the order in which I'm calling the modifier attributes, but switching the order of `.font(.body)` and `.lineLimit` doesn't change anything. I also tried removing the `.padding()`, and that doesn't work either.

```
List(clubData) { club in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                Text(club.name)
                    .font(.title)
                    .lineLimit(nil)

                Text(club.subtitle)
                    .lineLimit(4)
                    .font(.body)
            }
            .padding()
        }
```

Here's an image of what's happening:

[image]

Comment: It's in beta, expect the worst!

Comment: Expect **and report**. :-P

Comment: ah, I know it. Submitted a radar 

Comment: FYI, Xcode 11 beta 3 has the same issue.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You might also be helped with this answer for the Xcode 11 GM:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604599/30602

The summary is that inside other Builders you need to add `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to your Text() to get it to wrap.

Comment: thank you for a great tip! I've been looking for "why TextField does not respects lineLimit parameter in multiline mode (axis: .vertical)" and your answer helped me to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this.

For now if you wrap your views in a GeometryReader then it should respect the line limits

e.g.

```
GeometryReader { _ in
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Wrapping my Text view in Geometry reader solved my issue with text shrinkage on device rotation while using .font(.system(size: 120)), .minimumScaleFactor(0.1), and .lineLimit(1)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to download Xcode 11.2 BETA. Xcode 11 GM in The App Store also have the problem with .linelimit(nil) being capped at one line.

Answer (score 1):

**Dec 12th, 2019 with Xcode 11.2.1**

**DO NOT trust .lineLimit**, use frame to set appropriate height (according to your font size) to wrap your multi-lined text. And, **DO NOT use .lineSpacing** even you think you make enough height, SwiftUI must have a really 'special' way to determine if the VStack height is enough and how many lines to display.

Answer (score 0):

April 23, 2020, Xcode 11.4

In my case, I get movie description text from TMDB API, which is in dynamic length. And it is embedded in VStack.

It is really annoyed. Even I set .linelimit(nil), the line for description text, it will still have a limit and end up ignoring some text as "long decription...".