# Line Break with Text() in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I make a line break with Text() if the text is too long to display in one line?
(Something like lineBreakMode in UIKit)

If I type in a long string it just adds „...“ on the right side of the text.

Thanks!

Edit: I tried to combine it with a scroll view to be able to scroll if the text is too long, but if I add a scroll view it ignors .lineLimit()

Code:

ˋˋˋ

```
struct Homework: View {

var selectedWeek: String
var week: String = "10.-20."
var content: String = "" //Long string inside here

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ScrollView(isScrollEnabled: true, alwaysBounceHorizontal: false, alwaysBounceVertical: true, showsHorizontalIndicator: false, showsVerticalIndicator: true, content: {
            Text(content)
               .lineLimit(nil)
        })
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(week))
    }
}
}
```

ˋˋˋ

Comment: Have you done *any* searching on this on this site? Could you post what code you've tried? A very quick search on *[SwiftUI] multiple line" turns up no less than two answers, along with a dup. Maybe you could explain why they haven't worked for you? (And sure, if it's a different issue I'm apologizing in advance, but still asking for your code so maybe we could help you.)

Comment: You might be helped with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604599/30602

Answer (score 3):

lineLimit API is used whenever you want a specific number of lines in the Text, you just call this API with number of lines that you want. If you are not sure how many lines will the take, just give nil in the parameter.

```swift
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var demoText = "Start Typing"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField($demoText)
            Text(demoText)
                .lineLimit(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Without any extra code it works, but if I add a scroll view, it doesn‘t work... Sorry.

Comment: In that case Text should be scrollable. There will be no ... shown at the end of the text.

Comment: Shaafi Shovon, I am not able to scroll with this code. It shows "..." at the end of the text

Comment: If i embed the code that I have posted here in a ScrollView then the text label becomes horizontally scrollable. So I am not sure about your code, what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Yes this is what i mean with "it ignors .lineLimit()". The text displays in one scrollable line. I fixed the problem temporarily with a List...