# Text Label is not expanding according to string in ScrollView SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

[image]I simply added TextLabel in scrollview but it is displaying in 1 line only. Without scrollview it is working fine with full height of Label

```
 struct UserDetailView: View {

        var userObj:User?

        var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {

                    Text("Hi here is Erick jackson. We need to help you. We will help you. Anything new to learn from you. I am here for that reason.")
                        .background(Color.orange)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .lineLimit(5)
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal,30)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create a multi-line text inside a ScrollView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593120/how-do-you-create-a-multi-line-text-inside-a-scrollview-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `.fixedSize` modifier after your `Text("Hi here is Erick Jackson....")` :

```swift
...

Text("Hi here is Erick jackson. We need to help you. We will help you. Anything new to learn from you. I am here for that reason.")
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)

.background(Color.orange)

...
```